# How to close <img> tags using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have a html string example as below:

```
html = "<html><body><img src = "" style = ""></body></html>
```

How could I achieve the following:

```
html = "<html><body><img src = ""  style = ""></img></body></html>
```

I want to close the image tags for a standard XHTML format. Would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, please show your code/effort and what the actual problem is.

Comment: <img> is an empty element, so it doesn't need any closing tag...

Comment: In HTML `<img>` tags don't need to be closed; they have the empty content type. You can use `<img/>` if you want, because HTML5 will just ignore that `/`.

Comment: @Pointy This comment is incorrect. XHTML requires tags to be closed, because it's strict. HTML5 and XHTML is not the same.

Comment: @Clijsters Of course they're not the same. The question is quite unclear; the concept of "closing a tag with JavaScript" is strange, and my comment was made in hopes of eliciting more information from the OP.

Comment: @Pointy: TBF, the question does say "XHTML" in the last sentence.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder and it says "html" in its first :)

Comment: @Pointy: **:-)**

Comment: @ChhaviC. Are you **sure** you need to be using XHTML? Doing so correctly is very hard. For the vast majority of purposes, HTML is preferred to XHTML.

Comment: @Cerbrus I am trying to search the html string for <img tags and append </img> once it encounters '>' tag. This seems a bit complicated approach

Comment: @ChhaviC. — Does that mean the question you are trying to ask is "I have a string containing HTML and wish to transform it to XHTML?"

Comment: The html and xHTML tags are because I am rendering a PDF of my html page. The PDF conversion using Flying saucer searches for close tags.

Comment: "Flying Saucer is a pure-Java library" — I'd forget about trying to do this in JS and find an HTML parser for Java that can serialise to XHTML (and then pass the resulting XHTML to FS).

Comment: Ah, Flying Saucer. Well re-writing HTML written for the web with the intention of using it for Flying Saucer (which does in fact expect well-formed XML) would be tricky, to say the least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what your question is. I read it one way, but I think Quentin's right that I should have read it another way.

### The way I read it

...was that you wanted to know how to write an `img` tag in XHTML.

> I want to close the image tags for a standard XHTML format.

In XHTML, [void elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements) like `img` are written with a solidus (`/`) with a space in front of it prior to the `>` in the tag:

```
html = '<html><body><img src = ""  style = "" /></body></html>';
// ------------------------------------------^^
```

(Note I changed to `'` for the outer quotes, so that would be a syntactically-valid string.)

Since XHTML is XML and [the spec doesn't impose any further syntax restrictions over XML's own](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-xhtml-syntax.html#the-xhtml-syntax), presumably you could also write `<img ...></img>`. However, the XHTML 1 spec [says you should use `<img ... />` instead](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_2) because of *"...uncertain results in many existing user agents."*

Doing the `<img ... />` thing in HTML (not XHTML) is *tolerated*, but unnecessary. `<img src = "" style = "">` is perfectly correct in HTML. (Note that this is only for void elements. The XHTML `<div />` is correctly written `<div></div>` in HTML, because `div` is not a void element; `<div />` would be treated exactly like `<div>` in HTML.)

### Or possibly you meant...

...that you have a string with HTML in it, and want to **modify** it to be XHTML. If so, you want to use an HTML parser to parse the string, and then an XHTML serializer to turn it back into a string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have to render a PDF using Flying Saucer which searches for opening and closing tags for all the elements. Would be great of you could suggest some way to do so.

Comment: @ChhaviC.: I did: `<img .../>` is the correct XHTML, and `<img ...>` is the correct HTML. If this "Flying Saucer" requires `<img ...></img>`, it's fundamentally broken and I would recommend not using it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder — It looks like Flying Saucer is designed to process XML and accepts XHTML as a subset of that. `<img ...></img>` is perfectly fine XHTML, it just isn't HTML-compatible XHTML. As far as I can tell, FS will accept `<img/>` and `<img></img>`.

Comment: @Quentin: If it accepts XML, then it should accept `<img .../>`. (Are you quite sure that `<img></img>` is valid XHTML?)

Comment: @Quentin: The spec says [*This specification does not define any syntax-level requirements beyond those defined for XML proper.*](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-xhtml-syntax.html#the-xhtml-syntax) so you may well be right about that. TIL!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder — Yes, [Appendix C](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_2) forbids the non-minimised form as an additional requirement solely for HTML-compatible XHTML.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for your help but unfortunately Flying Saucer is too designed in a way that continues looking for </img> tags. Seems like I will have to write a script to search <img> and append </img> :(

Answer (score -2):

> There is no need for a closing img tag because its a void element.

```
eg:-

<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face">
```

Reference: https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/51ffd01c80ff33d5ba007c7c